Details panel not showing names for properties in Level Editor UE5
Why details panel property names are hidden. How to make them visible?
Its only values are becoming visible.


The column was completely dragged to left side.
https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/missing-field-names-in-blueprint-detail-panel-how-to-fix/1224820/7
